How to prevent unwanted account creation with Firebase
I have a working web application with Firebase authentication. I want it to be such that only I (via the Firebase console) can set up accounts and anybody can sign into the accounts that I've set up. Every account in this app can access the same data, no matter the account, and I have setup Firestore rules to only accept requests that are authenticated.
The root of the problem is that I do not know much about the best practices of Firebase, but to get to the point, what is preventing someone from running auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("email", "password") in the browser console, logging into that account, and gaining access to the data?

I have found that the simplest solution to my specific problem is to disable the "Enable Create (sign-up)" setting under Firebase Console > Authentication > User Actions.

With this done, attempting to run auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("email", "password"); fails and returns this error: Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: This operation is restricted to administrators only. (auth/admin-restricted-operation).


what is preventing someone from running auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("email", "password") in the browser console, logging into that account, and gaining access to the data?

Nothing, as long as you have enabled email authentication for your project.
You might want to look into validating new accounts with email links as well as blocking registration with Cloud Functions.
Also look into Fireabse App Check for additional protection (but it is not guaranteed to ensure that no one can abuse your system).

Alternatively, I've also found the a setting in the Firebase Console under Authentication > User Actions called "Enable Create (sign-up)." Is changing this setting to false enough of protect against any account creation aside from through the Firebase Console?

Did you try it? Does it work the way you expect?

Yes it does, as outlined in the answer below.
